# Помогите протестировать api для логина

Tags: android, android-studio, клиент-сервер, rest

У меня есть приложение со стартовым экраном входа, и мне дали апи для входа, я уже третий день гуглю но не могу понять как тестировать предоставленный апи. Мне скинули эту информацию в таком формате:

```
"error_code": 1, "message": "authorization_header_not_given"}, status="401")
"error_code": 2, "message": "wrong_authorization_header_format"}), status="401", mimetype="application/json")
"error_code": 3, "message": "access_token_expired"}), status="401", mimetype="application/json") # acces token expired need to refresh token
"error_code": 4, "message": "invalid_token"}), status="403", mimetype="application/json") # invalid token
"error_code": 5, "message": "not_found"}, status="404") # requested resource could not be found
"error_code": 0, "message": "you are successfully authorized"}) # there is no error, this is normal state if all ok
```

ну и адрес сервакак соответственно, я скачал программу Postman для этого тестирования, но не могу понять что и куда прописывать что-бы получить ответ от сервера. Буду благодарен за любую помощь и советы.

Comment: Скорее всего вам надо замокировать ответы сервера для разных ситуаций и получать ожидаемое поведение на UI, проверяя правильно ли оно отобразилось?

Comment: что такое замокировать? я вот сейчас могу сделать разные виды запросов типа get/post/head и я могу написать сколько угодно head и body хотя не понял что для чего

Comment: экран входа уже работает? или вам надо его реализовать? или же только тестировать?

Comment: у меня уже есть экран входа, и при нажатии на кнопку войти я перехожу на другое активити, но пока что вход не фильтруется то есть никакой проверки нету, а мне нужно как-то проверять пользователя который лоигнится

Comment: Из выложенной информации нету: адреса, куда отправляются запросы, также какие параметры необходимо передать для авторизации

Comment: Годная статья по тестированию postman https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/api-testing-using-postman-323670c89f6d

Comment: адрес у меня есть куда отправлять запросы, а параметры это логин и пароль

Comment: а формат запроса (GET/POST). От этого будет зависеть какой именно запрос вы будете отправлять (будут ли параметры в теле запроса или же в url. А если в url, то как они там обозначаются и т.д.)

Comment: И в каком формате сервер ждёт данные авторизации - форма, json, что-то ещё?

Comment: ну я форму буду заполнять для входа, а cлать он будет наверное в json, но не факт

Comment: Кто он? Не зная формат запроса протестировать можно только наугад. В доках постмана куцо описаны основные варианты: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization

Comment: ой, оно это приложение, я просто не сильно понял что значит слать данные авторизации форма, ну тип как json посылать я примерно знаю а вот как форму слышу впервые, если можно расскажите что имели в виду

Comment: форму обычно говорят когда надо делать POST www-url-encoded т.е. в теле идут параметры как будто их обычная HTML форма посылает. В постман это специально в этом режиме вбить можно